# Data structure/format of C3 data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am trying to get my array of objects in the format that is needed to create a C3 bar chart but I am having trouble categorizing my data with JavaScript.  Below is my JavaScript code.

```
data = [
  {Service:"Army",Permanent:20,Itinerant:754,Region:"Western"},
  {Service:"Air Force",Permanent:100,Itinerant:2,Region:"Eastern"},
  {Service:"Army",Permanent:10,Itinerant:7,Region:"Western"},
  {Service:"Air Force",Permanent:30,Itinerant:2,Region:"Eastern"}
]

var sumAry=[];

for (var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
   var val =sumAry.indexOf(data[x].Service);
  if(val === -1){
     var permanent += data[x].Permanent;
     sumAry.push(data[x].Service, permanent);
  }else{
    console.log("IN");
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/GYRKqE?editors=0012

The C3 chart looks for a data in the structure/format shown below:

```
        ['Army', 30],
        ['Airorce', 130],
        ['Navy', 190],
        ['Army1', 70],
        ['Airorce2', 130],
        ['Navy3', 100]
```

For each of the values, the 'Permanent' property will be added up to get the number part of the array.  It becomes an aggregate of all the information.

Comment: In your preferred data format, where is the number coming from? (i.e., the `30` in `['Army', 30],`)

Comment: can someone please explain the downvote?  I provided as much details as I can.

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but (at a glance) codepen links are less preferable than an inlined code snippet, your code is poorly formatted, and your question doesn't explain where that number in the preferred data format is coming from.

Comment: Format fixed and explanation of the number added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number in the preferred format comes from the `Permanent` property, you could use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your dataset.

```js
var data = [{
        Service: "Army",
        Permanent: 654,
        Itinerant: 754,
        Region: "Western"
    },
    {
        Service: "Air Force",
        Permanent: 9,
        Itinerant: 2,
        Region: "Eastern"
    },
    {
        Service: "Army",
        Permanent: 6,
        Itinerant: 7,
        Region: "Western"
    },
    {
        Service: "Air Force",
        Permanent: 9,
        Itinerant: 2,
        Region: "Eastern"
    }
];

var aggregates = data.map(function (o) {
    // map original objects to new ones with zeroed-out data
    return {
        Service: o.Service,
        Permanent: 0,
    }
}).filter(function (o, index, a) {
    // filter the list to have only unique `Service` properties
    var service = o.Service;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
        if (a[i].Service === service) {
            // break out of the loop when the first matching `Service` is found.
            break;
        }
    }
    // `i` is now the index of the first matching `Service`.
    // if it's the first occurrence of that `Service`, keep it, otherwise ditch it.
    return i === index;
});

data.forEach(function (o) {
    // loop through the aggregate list and get the matching `Service` property.
    var agg = aggregates.filter(function (p) {
        return o.Service === p.Service;
    })[0]; // first element is the match.
    // sum the `Permanent` properties.
    agg.Permanent += o.Permanent;
});

// now that the data has been aggregated, transform it into the needed structure.
var c3data = aggregates.map(function (d) {
    return [d.Service, d.Permanent];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(c3data));
```

Comment: What do I do if I needed the data to be like so,  [["Army", 660],["Air Force", 18]]  ?

Comment: @JustMe Updated answer to account for aggregated data.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I had to break it down and understand each piece to understand the whole.  I still need to look at it some more to fully grasp what you did.  Thank you!

Comment: @JustMe Glad I could help. I added comments to the answer to better explain it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for doing that.